# My Single Pass Gaussian Blur Looks Awful

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader, blur

I've based my shader on this single pass shadertoy here:
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XdfGDH

I applied the same shader and it looks like this:
[image]

Scaled up so you can see the faint tears in the texture. They look grid-like and not smooth at all.

When it should be looking like this:
[image]

Source image:
[image]

Here's my shader. Translated the shadertoy to GLSL 110

```
#version 110
uniform sampler2D texture;

float normpdf(float x, float sigma)
{
  return 0.39894*exp(-0.5*x*x / (sigma*sigma)) / sigma;
}


void main()
{
  vec3 c = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy).rgb;

  const int mSize = 11;
  const int kSize = const int((float(mSize) - 1.0) / 2.0);
  float kernel[mSize];
  vec3 final_color = vec3(0.0);

  // Create the kernel
  float sigma = 7.0;
  float Z = 0.0;
  for (int j = 0; j <= kSize; ++j)
  {
    kernel[kSize + j] = kernel[kSize - j] = normpdf(float(j), sigma);
  }

  //get the normalization factor (as the gaussian has been clamped)
  for (int j = 0; j < mSize; ++j)
  {
    Z += kernel[j];
  }

  //read out the texels
  for (int i = -kSize; i <= kSize; ++i)
  {
    for (int j = -kSize; j <= kSize; ++j)
    {
      final_color += kernel[kSize + j] * kernel[kSize + i] * texture2D(texture, (gl_TexCoord[0].xy + vec2(float(i), float(j)))).rgb;
    }
  }

  gl_FragColor = vec4(final_color / (Z*Z), 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sampling points are most likely messed up because you are not taking into account that texture texel size is in range [0; 1]. You need to divide offset coordinates by texture resolution. We can get texture resolution using [ivec2 textureSize(gsampler2D sampler, int lod)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/textureSize.xhtml) function.

So changing this

`final_color += kernel[kSize + j] * kernel[kSize + i] * texture2D(texture, (gl_TexCoord[0].xy + vec2(float(i), float(j)))).rgb;`

to this

`final_color += kernel[kSize + j] * kernel[kSize + i] * texture2D(texture, (gl_TexCoord[0].xy + vec2(float(i), float(j))/textureSize(texture, 0).xy)).rgb;`

will hopefully fix your shader.

Comment: but doesnt texCoord[0].xy always returns _texel_ values from 0.0 to 1.0?

Comment: @Maverick please notice that I divide not `texCoord[0].xy` but offset coordinates.

Comment: I'm assuming that fixed the grid stretch marks. its possible now that the shader is blurring it and why I can't see those lines anymore. The shader overall is still not working as seen here: https://streamable.com/8b5lt

Comment: @Maverick just tried the code and it works for me.

Comment: could you share the code in a pastebin? maybe theres something else I've missed.

Comment: @Maverick sure, https://pastebin.com/4j7BwAXG 
But I had to port it to the modern OpenGL version. Changes in the code are minimal, but it could be that something is wrong with your pipeline.

Comment: Aha I placed the texture size division in the right spot. Needed to divide vec2(i, j) and then add it to the tex coord. I was dividing the sum of all three. thanks!